# Vue render element based on given property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, bootstrap-vue

I have the below block

```
<div>
  <b-card no-body>
    <b-tabs pills card vertical no-key-nav v-model="step">
      <b-tab title="Subject" v-for="animal in animals" :key="animal" v-show="animal=1">
        <b-card-text>
          <enrollment-form>
          </enrollment-form>
        </b-card-text>
      </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

I am just trying to show one given component at a time. Problem is, I'm getting all tabs rendered at the same time. I was jsut going to use buttons to iterate "step" up as input comes in.

EDIT

```
Data below
  data: () => {
    return {
      step: 2,
      animals: Array(3),
    }
  },
```

Comment: try animal === 1 instead animal = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't combine `v-show` with `v-for` in the same element and use comparison instead of assignment :

```
  <b-tab title="Subject" v-for="animal in animals" :key="animal" >
        <b-card-text v-show="animal==1">
          <enrollment-form>
          </enrollment-form>
        </b-card-text>
      </b-tab>
```

Your data should be like :

```
  data: () => {
    return {
      step: 2,
      animals: [...Array(3)].map((_,i)=>i+1),
    }
  },
```

Comment: this seems like a better approach, but I'm left with the problem that I still see tab titles and none of the tabs have content. I edited/added my data properties as well if that helps.

Comment: That pretty much works/does what I want, only issue I have is that the actual "tab" (saying 'subject')  still shows up. I am able to only display the given content now with this, but still see the tab titles. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: do you mean each tab should have the index as title? if yes you could do `:title="animal"`

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to hide a given tab while not in use at all actually.

Comment: what about ```:title="`${animal===step?'Subject':''}`"```?